# angularjs - controller not loading my scenario

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am getting error instead of loading my `controller`.

I provide all my files, let any figureout the mistake please..

html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="tcpApp">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <base href="/">
    <title>TCP App</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/lib/fonts.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/lib/reset.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/tcp.css">
</head>
<body>

    <div class="wrapper" ng-view></div>

    <!--Libs -->
    <script src="js/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/lib/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/lib/angular-resource/angular-resource.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/lib/angular-route/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <!--scripts -->
    //loading controller as first
    <script src="js/script/controllers/homeController.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script> //app file
</body>
</html>
```

app.js :

```
"user strict";

var tcpAppHolder = angular.module("tcpApp", ["ngRoute"]);

tcpAppHolder
    .config(function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {

        $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

        $routeProvider
            .when ("/home", {
                templateUrl : "views/home.html",
                controller  : "homeController" //loading home controller
        });

        $routeProvider
            .otherwise ({
                templateUrl : "views/home.html",
                controller  : "homeController"
        });
});
```

homecontroller.js file:

```
"use strict";

angular.module("tcpApp.controllers")
    .controller("homeController", function ($scope) { //but not loading
        console.log("i am from home");
    });
```

error I am getting:

> Uncaught Error: [$injector:nomod] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.0/$injector/nomod?p0=tcpApp.controllers

Comment: it tells you in the URL of the error it doesnt know what `tcpApp.controllers `is

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please update your home controller with

```
angular.module("tcpApp")
    .controller("homeController", function ($scope) { //but not loading
        console.log("i am from home");
    });
```

Your module name was incorrect that was causing the issue. Please check now.

Comment: Nope, still not loading.

Comment: Try shuffling app.js and homecontroller.js

Comment: let me try. as like your before answer i get this error: `Uncaught Error: [$injector:nomod] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.0/$injector/nomod?p0=tcpApp(anonymous function) @ angular.js:38(anonymous function) @ angular.js:1953a @ angular.js:1877Q.bootstrap @ `

Answer (score 2):

Your module's name is `tcpApp`, not tcpApp.controllers. Edit your homecontroller.js file.

```
angular.module("tcpApp")
.controller("homeController", function ($scope) { //but not loading
    console.log("i am from home");
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Need to add tcpApp.controllers to your tcpAppHolder var.

```
var tcpAppHolder = angular.module("tcpApp", ["ngRoute", "tcpApp.controllers" ]);
```

Comment: I updated like yours, but still getting error as ` http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.0/$injector/nomod?p0=tcpApp.controllers`

Comment: @3gwebtrain clear your cache!!!! Or else you are injecting the same old `tcpApp.controllers` somewhere

Comment: @3gwebtrain Is the homeController.js file being loaded correctly? Check your console.